# autotest 4.4.6, zentest 4.4.1 not working in rails app for controller file (but works for spec file)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, autotest

I know there are a few questions already regarding autotest and zentest but my problem seems a little different. In my case, if I run with

```
autotest
```

nothing happens other than a status message saying "Waiting since..." with no tests being run. If I run it with

```
autotest -s rspec2
```

Then all my tests run. If I change a **spec** file autotest knows and re-runs my tests. But if I change a **controller** file then I just get my "Waiting since..." message updated but no tests are run.

Any ideas what's going on? Or can someone please point me where I can look into this further?

.autotest (i actually don't know if # is how to comment out a section!)

```
require 'autotest/fsevent'
#require 'autotest/restart'
require 'autotest/growl'
require 'autotest/timestamp'
```

I never use "sudo gem install" because I am using rvm. So only "gem install X"

Comment: Can I have a look at your .autotest file?

Comment: Have you installed the autotest rails gem? sudo gem install autotest-rails

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem looks very much similar to this [autotest on ubuntu does nothing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3622193/autotest-on-ubuntu-does-nothing)

Answer (score 0):

The only gem you need is `autotest`, so deinstall the rest. Optionally, you can use `autotest-fsevent` and `autotest-growl` on a mac.

Make sure there is an `autotest/discover.rb` with the following contents:

```
Autotest.add_discovery { "rails" }
Autotest.add_discovery { "rspec2" }
```

It should've been generated by `rails generate rspec:install`

If you have additional directories in your app directory, you add them to autotest by making a `.autotest` file, containing something like:

```
Autotest.add_hook :initialize do |at|
  at.add_mapping(%r%^spec/(.*)_spec\.rb$%) { |filename, _| filename }
  at.add_mapping(%r%^app/(.*)\.rb$%) { |_, m| ["spec/#{m[1]}_spec.rb"] }
end
```

(Answer based on Rails3 and RSpec2)

Comment: well, when i "gem install autotest" it installs zentest. and when i try running "autotest" at the command line it tells me i probably need autotest-rails. so at that point i have autotest, zentest, and autotest-rails gems installed.